# Where can I get longitudinal data of the COVID-19 cases?

Tags: survival

Where can I download a full dataset of the SARS-CoV-2 pandemics containing time information for each individual (date of infection, date of death, age, gender, weight, censoring information...)

It's important to get this information in order to do survival analyses and other studies.

I'm only able to find aggregated data. For example this Chinese dataset.
https://github.com/BlankerL/DXY-COVID-19-Data

Comment: There's something like this https://github.com/beoutbreakprepared/nCoV2019/blob/master/latest_data/latestdata.csv but maybe it hasn't the detail that you are looking for. I imagine that if this data exists then it won't be public.

Comment: We just ask the authorities to make the data available to universities and researchers signing a confidentiality contract.